# vimdiff: hop between 'blue' lines(lines with no corresponding text in file to compare)

Tags: vim, string-matching, vimdiff

I have to compare two (assembly) files and see where the instructions do not match.

In the vimdiff I use there are two colors to mark the difference in text.
1. blue: when there is no text in the other file to compare.
2. pink: when both files have similar text but they differ in a few characters.

The lines which match completely have a black background.

I am looking for a shortcut to hop from one 'blue' area to the next.
[image: Sample]

Comment: Try this http://superuser.com/questions/145940/vimdiff-jump-to-next-difference-inside-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[c` to jump to the previous change and `]c` to jump to the next change.

And read `:h diff`.

Comment: using [c and ]c jumps to the next 'change'. Is there a way to switch only to the next 'blue' region. The file I have to diff is quite big and I do not need to look at the 'pink' areas. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: No, those are the only buit-in shortcuts for jumping up and down in a diffed window. Did you search on vim.org for a possible plugin?

Comment: Not yet. Although the the link posted by @Xavjer in the comment seems a possible solution.